# why is this nearly same code producing different results

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

hello I am very new to coding and am working on a Caesar cipher. However for this code`

```
def encoder():
user_string=str(input('Enter text to encrypt'))
shift=int(input('Enter number to shift letters by'))
for i in range(len(user_string)):
    char=user_string[i]
    value=ord(char)
    new_value=value+shift
    new_value=chr(new_value)
    print(new_value,end='')
def decoder():
user_string=str(input('Enter text to decrypt'))
shift=int(input('Enter number to shift letters by'))
for i in range(len(user_string)):
    char=user_string[i]
    value=ord(char)
    new_value=value-shift
    new_value=chr(new_value)
    print(new_value,end='')
```

When I plug in something like Hello world it returns the correct result but with a # replacing the space. And when I plug in the encrypted result back into the decoder it returns the string with no spaces at all. The only difference between the two should be the use of newvalue = value + shift for the encoding and then newvalue = value-shift for the decryption. Can somebody help me understand why it is doing this and also how to fix the issue of the # in the encryption and no spaces in the decryption. Thank you. EDIT the shift value that I am using is 3 and the exact string is Hello world for the encryption and the encoded version of the same for the decryption.

Comment: What is the exact string that is causing wrong answer?

Comment: I have been Hello world or the encryption and then Khoor zruog for the decryption which should come out to be Hello world when used with a shift value of 3.

Comment: I just tried with Hello world with a shift value 2 and it works.

Comment: The space ' ' is also shifted, hence you are not getting the same.

Comment: Did you type a space by any chance before writing your text? That seems to me the only possible reason why it's not working

Comment: is there any way I could edit this to get it to skip over the spaces so that the format of the original string is preserved? or would i need to go about it in a completely different way?

Comment: You can just tell it not to apply the shift if `char` is a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because space is also shifted by 3. Your program is absolutely correct.

The [ASCII code for space is 32](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii/ascii-space.html) and for # is 35.

`encoder()` with `Hello world` & `3` shift should result `Khoor#zruogv`

`decoder()` with `Khoor#zruogv` & `3` shift should result `Hello world`

If you want the space to not shift, and display as space, you can put an if statement inside the for loop.

```
for i in range(len(user_string)):
    char=user_string[i]
    if char == ' ':
        print(char, end='')
        continue
    value=ord(char)
    new_value=value+shift
    new_value=chr(new_value)
    print(new_value,end='')
```

Comment: Thank you! This advice solved my problem very quickly and I am quite grateful.

Comment: @MustafaShahzad Please select his answer as a solution if it solved your issue